# Split dataframes in a user defined function in R

Tags: r, split

I created a function where at the end I would like to retrieve a list of dataframes splitted from a dataframe by a variable that I call as an argument of the function. Here is a simplified version :

```
dataframe <-
  as.data.frame(cbind(
    ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    TRT01AN = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2),
    AGEGR1 = c(
      "Adult",
      "Child",
      "Adolescent",
      "Adolescent",
      "Adolescent",
      "Child"
    )
  ))



sub1 <- function(SUB1) {
list1 = split(dataframe,datafram${{SUB1}})
  return(list1)
}

list1 <- sub1(AGEGR1)
```

When I try with

```
list1 = split(dataframe,datafram${{SUB1}})
```

I have this error:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"sub1 <- function(SUB1) {
list1 = split(dataframe,dataframe${"
```

And when I tried with this:

```
split(final2, with(final2, interaction(AGEGR1), drop = TRUE) )
```

I have this error:

```
Error in interaction({ : object 'AGEGR1' not found
```

Any ideas how I can solve this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `[[` to subset the dataframe in a user defined function. It is also a good practice to pass dataframe as argument to the function instead of relying it to be evaluated in global environment.

```
sub1 <- function(data, SUB1) {
  list1 = split(data,data[[SUB1]])
  return(list1)
}

list1 <- sub1(dataframe, "AGEGR1")
list1

#$Adolescent
#  ID TRT01AN     AGEGR1
#3  3       3 Adolescent
#4  4       2 Adolescent
#5  5       2 Adolescent

#$Adult
#  ID TRT01AN AGEGR1
#1  1       1  Adult

#$Child
#  ID TRT01AN AGEGR1
#2  2       1  Child
#6  6       2  Child
```